# How to call a waterfall dialog in a Dialog - Azure Bot builder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-bot-service

In my azure bot, I have the default bot "DialogBot.cs". In its OnMessageActivityAsync() method, I am wanting to call a specific waterfall based on user input.

Once I parse the input however, I don't know how to trigger the specific waterfall. Lets say the waterfall is called 'SpecificDialog'. I tried this:

`await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(SpecificDialog)), cancellationToken)`;

but that doesn't work. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: I apologize for the delay! Yes, your answer was great. I upvoted but don't have enough reputation for it to be displayed unfortunately. Hopefully you can still clear this from your support tracker!

Comment: No problem! Just wanted to make sure you got all the help you needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with one of the Samples. I'll base my answer off of [CoreBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot).

You should think of the dialog called by `Dialog.RunAsync()` as the "root" or "parent" dialog from which all other dialogs branch and flow from. To change which dialog is called by this, look in [`Startup.cs` for a line that looks like this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Startup.cs#L44):

```cs
// Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogAndWelcomeBot<MainDialog>>();
```

To change that to a dialog other than `MainDialog`, you just replace it with the appropriate dialog.

Once you're in your root or parent dialog, you [call another dialog with `BeginDialogAsync()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L63):

```cs
stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), new BookingDetails(), cancellationToken);
```

---

FYI to others:

This works just a little bit different in Node. In CoreBot, [the MainDialog is passed to the bot in `index.js`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/index.js#L81):

```js
const dialog = new MainDialog(luisRecognizer, bookingDialog);
const bot = new DialogAndWelcomeBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);

[...]

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
```

You can see that it calls [`DialogAndWelcomeBot`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/bots/dialogAndWelcomeBot.js), which extends [DialogBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/bots/dialogBot.js), [which calls `MainDialog` on every message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/bots/dialogBot.js#L28):

```js
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
    console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');

    // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
    await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);

    // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
    await next();
    });
```

You don't *have* to set your bot up this way, but it's the currently recommended design and you'll have an easier time implementing our docs and samples if you follow this.

Comment: To clarify on this, if I use a root dialog, that will run by default when no other dialogs are ongoing? I am currently just starting dialogs (based on LUIS intent) in my bot.js file.

Comment: @billoverton Yes and no. I added a description to my answer. Should clarify things.